# ImportError при импорте модуля из одноименного пакета

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, python-import

Я пытаюсь импортировать из scipy функцию для расчета коэффициента корреляции

```
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
```

При попытке исполнить код выдается сообщение об ошибки

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль
```

Тоже самое происходит если я пытаюсь импортировать не одноименные модуль из пакета где есть модуль с названием как это пакет. Так в папке interpolate хранится модуль interpolate, в результате чего эта команда

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
```

Приводит к той же самой ошибке.
Если одноименных модулей в парке нет то все работает. К примеру

```
from scipy.cluster import vq
```

И в другой библиотеке таких проблем не возникает даже если в папке есть одноименный модуль

```
from openpyxl.workbook import workbook
```

Пробовал переименовать название модуля из stats в stat, но тогда появляется ошибка

```
ImportError: No module named 'scipy.stats.stats'
```

Версия питона anaconda 3.5.0, windows 8.1Х64

Comment: Попробуйте установить отсюда: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Comment: @gil9red извините за поздний ответ, не заметил ваш комментарий раньше. Я пробовал установить модуль с этого сайта, но появилась ошибка: Package missing in current win-64 channels. Пришел я в результате к тому что установил scipy на базовый дистрибутив python. Там все работает.

Comment: т.е. проблема решена? Тогда поставьте решение в ответ :)

Comment: @gil9red Проблема в том что scipy не работает нормально на анаконде. Коэффициент корреляции, конечно, можно посчитать и другими средствами.